# 3 divs in a row with position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set 3 divs in a row in Flex.

**FIXED 1:** The centered div is to set to `position: fixed`. The other 2 divs on both sides are not lined up with the centered fixed div when scrolling. If I set the centered div `position: sticky` it drops down to the middle of the page instead of the top.

**FIXED 2:** Also I placed a shape element way behind these 3 divs. The 2 divs (both sides) should go under the shape set to `z-index: -1` on both sides and that didnt work.

The 2 divs on both sides has `padding-top: 450px` to keep the content lower than the centered div as shown on screenshot of prototype.

(UPDATED) - **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/4t8nef6m/76/)** for the **PROBLEM** #2.

**This prototype design in Adobe XD exactly how it should look like -**

(UPDATED) - [image]

Your help is really appreciated!

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #12212A;
}

.body-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: #12212A;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-profile {
  color: white;
  border: #3D4B57 solid 1px;
}

.body-wrapper>.row-profile {
  flex: 1 1 30%
}

#profile-left {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 44px;
  padding-top: 450px;
  height: 1520px;
  width: 455px;
  background-color: #12212A;
}

#profile-center {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3D4B57;
  padding-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 366px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
}

#profile-right {
  padding-left: 44px;
  padding-top: 450px;
  height: 1520px;
  width: 455px;
  background-color: #12212A;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrapper">
  <div class="row-profile" id="profile-left">LEFT (content see JSFiddle link)</div>
  <div class="row-profile" id="profile-center">CENTER LEFT (content see JSFiddle link)</div>
  <div class="row-profile" id="profile-right">RIGHT (content see JSFiddle link)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the question \ problem?

Comment: When you set the position of an element to fixed it disregards any flexbox you have, im not sure whats the desired result you are trying to achieve

Comment: If you don't need a real page-wide fixed .profile-center you might try a position:sticky;
sticky element will follow the scroll while its parent is in a browser viewport.

Comment: @Jared - did you really read the code? The centered div is only set to position fixed not the whole page. SMH

Comment: 'position:fixed' elements are removed from the flow and do not affect their sibling or parent elements layout. 'fixed' elements are positioned relative to viewport - this is what i meant 'page-wide'. Your left/right divs with flex-grow:1 will fill their parent and overlap with a center. With a flex-grow:0 set they will be centered coz of their parent justify-content:center.
I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but probably following fix will help:
- for your center replace 'position:fixed' with 'position:sticky;' and add 'align-self:flex-start' to bring element to its parent top.

Comment: @Jared - That `align-self: flex-start` worked for me - thank you! Now Im trying to figure out how to scroll left/right div behind the shape element. Thanks again!

Comment: With a shape it is still a z-index trick. I'll post it as an answer since it requires some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second problem - the shape itself:

```
.body-wrapper::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;right: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Adding a higher z-index for the center element will bring it above the shape:

```
#profile-center{
    z-index: 20;
}
```

If you need your shape to be bound to viewport top change *position:absolute* to *position:fixed*.

Comment: Ok, here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/4t8nef6m/72/ - it looks like the center div is working and red shape on top will not stick as I set it to `position: sticky` when scrolling up. The divs on both sides should go behind the red shape above when scrolling up. Thanks again!

Comment: I have issues with opening jsfiddle.
`position: sticky` leaves an element in the flow, so if you need the shape to behave like somewhat locally-fixed it is gonna be tricky, since the shape is still a flex-element. 
So you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.body-wrapper`, control flex-basis for left/right/center to avoid wrapping, add a `flex-basis: 100%` and a negative `margin-bottom` (equal to the height) to the shape. I dislike the solution using negative margins and fixed-pixels, but cannot invent something better right now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/4t8nef6m/76/

Comment: Ah! I changed `position: sticky` to `position: fixed` and it worked! Thank you so much for your time! You rock!

Comment: Glad it helped, cheers.